# Where is qembed tool in QT4.5?

Tags: qt, qt4, qt-creator

Or how could i embed .qm files into my application?

I'm using qt-creator.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The qembed tool was made obsolete by the [Qt Resource System](http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.5/resources.html).